# DataTables Add aria role and aria expanded for the details-control ( Plus/Minus Button )

Tags: datatables

How can I Add an aria role and an aria expanded for the details-control ( Plus/Minus Button ) which is used to show hide additional columns during responsiveness .

Add an appropriate role (role=”button”)  . Add and update the state (aria-expanded=”true”) for the Plus/Minus Button.

I need this for the accessibility purpose.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We managed to implement this using the recommendation mentioned here  https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/55221/add-aria-role-and-aria-expanded-for-the-details-control-plus-minus-button